# How can I construct a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Construct a matrix whose one eigenvector is $(1,-1,1,-1)$.

Here only one eigenvector is given and I need to construct a matrix with this. I don't know how to proceed. Please help.

Comment: Use Gram-Schmidt and conjugation with diagonal matrix.

Comment: To be clear: it has to have only that one eigenvector? Or are other eigenvectors allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer** -- Every nonzero vector is an eigenvector of the identity matrix.

**Long answer** -- For a nontrivial example, consider
$$
A = P\pmatrix{1&1\\ &\ddots&\ddots\\ &&\ddots&1\\ &&&1}P^{-1}
$$
where $P$ is any invertible matrix with $(1,-1,1,-1)^T$ as it first column. (Use $A^T$ if you need $(1,-1,1,-1)$ to be a *row* eigenvector.)

Comment: The question seems to suggest there is only a single eigenvector, up to a scalar?

Comment: @ZachL. Thanks. Edited.

Comment: In short: it is well-known that Jordan blocks have only one eigenvector (they are *defective* matrices), so apply a similarity transformation to a Jordan block, using 1551's prescription for the similarity transformation.